# Missing ApexTestRunResult Data

Tags: tooling-api, tooling, apextestrunresult

Yesterday we had 10-11 records and today just 2. This is what I did:

Check recycle bin and using All Data

Check Bulk API delete capable processes and users

Check connected apps.

DataLoader.io SSO doesnt work so couldnt check there

Tried putting a trace on ApexTestRunResult but you cant do that on tooling api objects

Checked the audit logs, and nothing there.

Does Salesforce purge the data in ApexTestRunResult  by itself? I couldnt find any documentation.

WHat else can I do to track down what happened? Does salesforce purge this data themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They most certainly do get automatically deleted. If they weren't purged periodically they would eventually add up to a significant number of records.

Looking in the Dev org I'm currently connected to I can see `ApexTestRunResult` records dating back to **14-Jan-20 1:36:57 AM**. So about a month ago.

Note that all the `ApexTestRunResult` records are parented by an [`AsyncApexJob`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) via the `AsyncApexJobId` field. If anything were to delete the AsyncApexJob record the corresponding test run result would also be deleted.

There is a [doc that indicates Salesforce automatically deletes these AsyncApexJob records](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318945&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1):

> Completed AsyncApexJob records are automatically purge by salesforce after 7 days.

Oddly, that timeframe seems to contradict the currently month of examples in my dev org.

It is possible that someone used the [`System.purgeOldAsyncJobs(dt);`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_purgeOldAsyncJobs) method to explicitly remove the jobs before Salesforce automatically purged them.

Another possibility, perhaps more likely, is the **Clear Test Data** button from the Apex Test Execution history page or the equivalent from the Developer Console **Test > Clear Test Data** option. Those immediately remove the `ApexTestRunResult` records.